# How to repair a corrupt CDC in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, cdc

The Change Data Capture set up in my SQL Server is now corrupt. The generated CDC objects are missing. When we try to run the sys.sp_cdc_enable_db, it says that cdc is already enabled. When we try to run sys.sp_cdc_disable_db to clean up, we are getting the error below. I'm not sure what else to do.

> Msg 22831, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_cdc_disable_db_internal,
>   Line 262 [Batch Start Line 9] Could not update the metadata that
>   indicates database [mydb] is not enabled for Change Data Capture. The
>   failure occurred when executing the command '(null)'. The error
>   returned was 3930: 'The current transaction cannot be committed and
>   cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the
>   transaction.'. Use the action and error to determine the cause of the
>   failure and resubmit the request.

The db owner is already SA.

Comment: It looks like there might be an open transaction holding up your log file. Have you tried running `DBCC OPENTRAN` to see if anything suspicious turns up?

Comment: The only open transactions are the ones initiated by the sys.sp_cdc_disable_db SP.